# Like/dislike button system in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have a like and dislike button and when one of them is clicked, it will change a colour to red. But when I click both, both like and dislike icons turn out to be red. I want only one of them to be red at all times not both. How do I fix it?

I'm wondering if I can write the code shorter by using CSS and .hasClass, .removeClass and .addClass in Jquery OR toggle.

Below is the jQuery code that I've written:

```
$('#Like').on({
'click': function() {
    if($('#Like').attr('src') == 'images/Like.png') {
        $('#Like').attr('src','images/Liked.png');
        $('#Dislike').attr('src') == 'images/Dislike.png');
    }
    else {
        $('#Like').attr('src','images/Like.png');
    }
}
});

$('#Dislike').on({
'click': function() {
    if($('#Dislike').attr('src') == 'images/Dislike.png') {
        $('#Dislike').attr('src','images/Disliked.png');
        $('#heartLike').attr('src') == 'images/Like.png');
    }
    else {
        $('#Dislike').attr('src','images/Dislike.png');
    }
}
});
```

Here, #like and #dislike are the original like and dislike icons.

Like.png and Dislike.png are the images without colour and Liked.png and Disliked.png are the images with filled in red colour.

Comment: When receiving an answer, please do not update your question with that answer. The result of doing so is a question that claims to have a problem with working code, and an answer that does not make sense in light of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, You were using different id's for like button in your code. On dislike click you were changing the url of heartLike, changed this to Like.

```
$('#Like').on({'click': function() {
if($('#Like').attr('src') == 'images/Like.png') {
    $('#Like').attr('src','images/Liked.png');
    $('#Dislike').attr('src') == 'images/Dislike.png');
}
else {
    $('#Like').attr('src','images/Like.png');
}
 }
});

$('#Dislike').on({'click': function() {
if($('#Dislike').attr('src') == 'images/Dislike.png') {
    $('#Dislike').attr('src','images/Disliked.png');
    $('#Like').attr('src') == 'images/Like.png');
}
else {
    $('#Dislike').attr('src','images/Dislike.png');
}
 }
});
```

Best of luck :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use common class to bind the click handler, specific classes i.e. `like` and `dislike` CSS class for state, I would also recommend you to show `icon` using CSS rule. Here is a generic example

```js
$('span.common').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('like dislike')
});
```

```css
.like {
  background-color: green
}
.dislike {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="common like">loren</span>
<br />
<span class="common dislike">ipsum</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Like').on({
'click': function() {
    if($('#Like').attr('src') == 'images/Like.png') {
        $('#Like').attr('src','images/Liked.png');
        $('#Dislike').attr('src','images/Dislike.png');
    }
    else {
        $('#Like').attr('src','images/Like.png');
    }
}
});

$('#Dislike').on({
'click': function() {
    if($('#Dislike').attr('src') == 'images/Dislike.png') {
        $('#Dislike').attr('src','images/Disliked.png');
        $('#heartLike').attr('src','images/Like.png');
    }
    else {
        $('#Dislike').attr('src','images/Dislike.png');
    }
}
});
```